# Reading config with .NET Core and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core

In trying to read configuration in a .Net Core 2.0 project from multiple providers, I am not getting the desired result.

I added the following NuGet packages to a stock .Net Core C# project to read the config. Both installed version `2.0.2`.

> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

This is the code to demonstrate the problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var InMemoryValue = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            ["Configuration.Test1"] = "IndexerValue1",
            ["Configuration.Test2"] = "IndexerValue2",
        };

        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder
            .AddInMemoryCollection(InMemoryValue)
            .AddJsonFile("Config.json")
            ;
        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine("Indexer");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test1:{configuration["Configuration.Test1"]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test2:{configuration["Configuration.Test2"]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test3:{configuration["Configuration.Test3"]}");

        var getConfig = configuration.Get<Configuration>();
        Console.WriteLine("Get");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test1:{getConfig.Test1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test2:{getConfig.Test2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test3:{getConfig.Test3}");

        var bindConfig = new Configuration();
        configuration.GetSection("Configuration").Bind(bindConfig);
        Console.WriteLine("Bind");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test1:{bindConfig.Test1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test2:{bindConfig.Test2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Test3:{bindConfig.Test3}");

        Console.Write("Press [Enter] to end.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private class Configuration
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public string Test2 { get; set; }
        public string Test3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of the `Config.json` file.

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "Test1": "JsonValue1",
    "Test3": "JsonValue3"
  }
}
```

And lastly, here is the output.

```
Indexer
  Test1:IndexerValue1
  Test2:IndexerValue2
  Test3:
Get
  Test1:
  Test2:
  Test3:
Bind
  Test1:JsonValue1
  Test2:
  Test3:JsonValue3
Press [Enter] to end.
```

As I understand it, I believe I should get `JsonValue1`, `IndexerValue2`, and `JsonValue3` in every section.
Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: The Configuration indices (["Configuration.Test1"]) use a colon not a dot to access the config hierarchy. So, change to ["Configuration:Test1"]. The second section would need to be refactored, as it is trying to use reflection to match the fields, which cannot be found. In any event, the second test appears to be solved by the third test, and therefore unnecessary.

Comment: @JamieMeyer ah man, I knew that too. Thank you very much for showing me my mistake. The second group is still null but I can use the third bind method well enough. If you post as answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment... Change the references to colons, and omit the second case. That seems to be redundant. Here is the code that I came up with.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var InMemoryValue = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                ["Configuration:Test1"] = "IndexerValue1",
                ["Configuration:Test2"] = "IndexerValue2",
            };

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder
                .AddInMemoryCollection(InMemoryValue)
                .AddJsonFile("Config.json")
                ;
            var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            Console.WriteLine("Indexer");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test1:{configuration["Configuration:Test1"]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test2:{configuration["Configuration:Test2"]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test3:{configuration["Configuration:Test3"]}");

            var bindConfig = new Configuration();
            configuration.GetSection("Configuration").Bind(bindConfig);
            Console.WriteLine("Bind");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test1:{bindConfig.Test1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test2:{bindConfig.Test2}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Test3:{bindConfig.Test3}");

            Console.Write("Press [Enter] to end.");
            Console.Read();
        }
        public class Configuration
        {
            public string Test1 { get; set; }
            public string Test2 { get; set; }
            public string Test3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```